# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space cloning project from TFS to local machine

Tags: tfs, bitbucket, clone, git-tf

I am getting Java heap space error while cloning the project from TFS to local machine using `git-tf`.

> http://dsiServer1:8080/tfs/Project1 "$/Biling/Dev" C:\TFSProjects\Dev
>   --deep Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional
>   Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified
>   Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar" Connecting to
>   TFS... Cloning $/IPNS Billing/Dev into C:\TFSProjects\Dev: 5%,
>   Subs_StartBr.html Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.UnpackedObject.open(UnpackedObject.java:135)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openObject2(ObjectDirectory.java:469)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openObject1(ObjectDirectory.java:360)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileObjectDatabase.openObjectImpl1(FileObjectDatabase.java:173)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileObjectDatabase.openObject(FileObjectDatabase.java:158)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:145)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.reset(CanonicalTreeParser.java:201)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.createSubtreeIterator0(CanonicalTreeParser.java:235)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.createSubtreeIterator(CanonicalTreeParser.java:213)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.createSubtreeIterator(CanonicalTreeParser.java:60)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.enterSubtree(TreeWalk.java:912)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:126)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.core.tasks.CreateCommitForChangesetVersionSpecTask$ChangesetCommitItemReader.getFileObjectId(CreateCommitForChangesetVersionSpecTask.java:409)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.core.tasks.CreateCommitForChangesetVersionSpecTask.createBlob(CreateCommitForChangesetVersionSpecTask.java:244)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.core.tasks.CreateCommitForChangesetVersionSpecTask.run(CreateCommitForChangesetVersionSpecTask.java:180)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.core.tasks.framework.TaskExecutor.execute(TaskExecutor.java:145)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.core.tasks.CloneTask.run(CloneTask.java:232)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.core.tasks.framework.TaskExecutor.execute(TaskExecutor.java:145)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.CloneCommand.run(CloneCommand.java:216)
>           at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main.main(Main.java:328)

Comment: `git-tf` is no longer maintained. `git-tfs` is an equivalent tool that is better supported.

Comment: Thanks for the the suggestion Shayki. I have Increased heap size to  \git-tf.cmd file to  4 gb using below command.                                                                               java -ea -Xmx4096M -cp %GITTF_CLASSPATH% "-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=%BASE_DIRECTORY%native" com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main %*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Increased heap size for \git-tf.cmd file to 4 gb using below command.

java -ea -Xmx4096M -cp %GITTF_CLASSPATH% "-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=%BASE_DIRECTORY%native" com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main %*

Comment: It took 42 hours to copy 6 GB project from TFS to local machine